# Facebook Messenger Sender Actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to use Sender Actions as described in the messenger [Send API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/sender-actions/). However when I send a **typing_on** POST I do no see anything happen in messenger. I have tried on chrome desktop and the messenger android app.

I am able to send a **mark_seen** POST and this does update the chat with an icon indicating my message has been seen.

The request body looks as follows:-

```
{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "sender_action":"typing_on"
}
```

When sending **mark_seen**, **typing_on** or **typing_off** I always get the following response body.

```
{
    "recipient_id": "<PSID>"
}
```

Are there additional steps needed to get the typing indicator to display? Does it only work on a specific platform? I cannot find any more documentation, and I am not getting any error messages, the POST status comes back OK identically when sending **mark_seen** or **typing_on**, I just can't see any effect after **typing_on**.

Comment: I think you are doing everything correctly. It may be something Facebook has done lately. Our bot was setting this action
on as soon as message was delivered to server (after marking it seen). I noticed today it doesn't work anymore. Just stopped.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know someone else has the same issue, I'd not be surprised if it was an issue on Facebook's end, I'll try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got reply from Facebook developer team on Facebook Developers group
Quote:
"This changed recently for mobile and is currently assigned to an internal team". Looks like something internal.

Comment: Started working at last for me today, with no code changes. So can only assume that they fixed the issue on Facebook's end.

Comment: looks like issue is user and/or page and/or app specific. I saw typing icon with our qa page linked to qa app. now I see it on the page linked to production app but another user doesn't. They must be working on it.

Comment: I also got the same issue for typing_on. Does anyone know if this has been fixed?